# Use of Nullable Type in method gives error

Tags: c#, nullable

I have created a property within a class that is a nullable integer:

```
private int? submittedAge {get; set;}
```

I am doing this as the user may or may not enter an age. Later in the application I do a check before making use of this property, and if it is NOT null, I pass it along to a method that requires an integer.

```
if (this.submittedAge != null)
{
  result = utilityClass.GetPeopleWithMatchingAge(this.submittedAge);
}
```

Intellisense gives me an error saying the method call has some invalid arguments.

If I change the `submittedAge` property back to a non-Nullable integer then all is well.

Perhaps I am not understanding the proper use of a nullable type.

Comment: And the downvote was because of?

Comment: Looks like a valid question to me. It's based on a misconception, but it's a somewhat common and perfectly understandable misconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your method takes an `int` not `int?`, you need to change your parameter type or add an overload.

Or you can just pass the value using `.Value` property:

```
result = utilityClass.GetPeopleWithMatchingAge(this.submittedAge.Value);
```

Comment: Even though I would never actually call the method when the type is null? Perhaps it is because C# sees the `nullable` type as a completely different type?

Comment: @webworm It is a completely different type. `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @webworm It's just like how given `void f(string s)`, and an `object o`, C# doesn't let you write `if (o is string) { f(o); }`. Static typing can be very strict.

Comment: nullable types _are_ completely different types.

Comment: What is considered the "Best Practice" in a case such as this? Use the "Value" as in `this.submittedAge.Value` or use `int?` in the method definition.

Comment: @webworm int? to int requires an explicit cast. Because null is not convertible to int, when you know there is in fact an underlying value you can use explicit cast too: `(int)this.submittedAge`. and you can avoid adding an overload if you don't want to handle nullable ints differently in your method.

Comment: @webworm The best practice is whatever is appropriate for `GetPeopleWithMatchingAge` - its signature shouldn't change to suit its callers.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.submittedAge.HasValue)
{
   result = utilityClass.GetPeopleWithMatchingAge(this.submittedAge.Value);
}
```

or if you want to have your code handle a specific default value, you can do this

```
result = utilityClass.GetPeopleWithMatchingAge(this.submittedAge.GetValueOrDefault(-1));
```

in that case, if the user hasn't specified a value, submittedAge will return -1.

If you'd like to see what it is doing underneath the covers and why there is no explicit cast available, the source code is available [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Nullable@cs/1305376/Nullable@cs)

Comment: @TyCobb It is basically the same as using coalesce and I find that easier to read. `(this.submittedAge ?? -1)`